# Why does my Image push my text below my header?

Tags: html, css

Why does my Image push my text bellow my header
I can't figure out why, but my text(that will later become menu drop downs) will not align with the image that is in the header with it. I tried making my header longer, which made it so the text was in the header but the text still wont align. How can I align the text with the image in the header and why was there a problem in the first place?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #6441a5;
}
#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: right;
  color: red;
}
#header img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<title>Twitch Support</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.twitch.tv/favicon.ico">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<body>
  <div id='header'>
    <img src="http://gamingshogun.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/TwitchTV-logo.png" alt="TwitchTV-logo" width="150.8px" height="50px">
    <div style="margin-left:100px;">
      <ul id='menu'>
        <li>
          <p>Get Help Now</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Viruses</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>About</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>



</body>
```

[image]

Comment: There are several ways to do this. Set #header img (plus margin-right) and #header ul to display inline and remove the div around the UL. Example:
`#header img {display: inline; margin-right:100px; } #menu { display: inline; }`

Comment: See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f5xwmsyt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image (`#header img`) and the `div`that comes after it are both block elements - by default block elements span the whole width, so they will be displayed below each other.
Use `display: inline-block`with a `width` definition to place divs next to each other.

edit / addition after comments:

- add `#menu { margin: 0; }` to get rid of the white space on top
- take out the `<p>` tags in your `<li>` elements.
- Use `margin-top` on `#menu li' to fine-tune the distance from the top border.

See also this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPWJYO

Comment: I did that. The text did not align with the image but the space between them did get larger. Maybe you could add updated code just to make sure I didn't miss anything in your instructions.

Comment: Ok, so I changed the code to this: http://pastebin.com/TnxXuWkp and also enlarged the font. Now there is white space at the top and the text is not on the header please can you help me.

Answer (score 1):

the text was showing up under the photo because the elements weren't floated.

add `float: left` to the image and `float: right` to the menu and they should align next to each other.

you could also use `float: left` on the menu instead if you don't want the items so far away from the image.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #6441a5;
}
#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: right;
  color: red;
  float: right;
}
#header img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<title>Twitch Support</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.twitch.tv/favicon.ico">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<body>
  <div id='header'>
    <img src="http://gamingshogun.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/TwitchTV-logo.png" alt="TwitchTV-logo" width="150.8px" height="50px">
    <div style="margin-left:100px;">
      <ul id='menu'>
        <li>
          <p>Get Help Now</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Viruses</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>About</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use float:left to left them in one row.Use margin-right to set space between them.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#menu ul{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: right;
  color: red;
  float: left;
}
.block-left{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #6441a5;
}
#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: right;
  color: red;
  float: left;
}
#header img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-right:100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<title>Twitch Support</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.twitch.tv/favicon.ico">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<body>
  <div id='header'>
    <img src="http://gamingshogun.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/TwitchTV-logo.png" alt="TwitchTV-logo" width="150.8px" height="50px">
    <div id='block-right'  style="">
      <ul id='menu'>
        <li>
          <p>Get Help Now</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Viruses</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>About</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>



</body>
```